# How can i record a video using ffmpeg in a better quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

Now i'm using this line in the Command Prompt window:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p outspaceships.mp4
```

When uploading it to youtube i see the only quality is 360p.
Is there any way to change this line to record in higher quality ? Maybe 720p/i or even 1080p/i ?

Screenshot of the console window:

[image: Console window]

Comment: The default behavior for gdigrab is to capture the full screen if `-i desktop` is used. Show your complete console output from your command: it will show the output width x height.

Comment: Output size is 1920x1080. For next time, please copy and paste the text instead of making an image of text. I don't know why 360p is the only available option. Can you provide a link to the YouTube video?

Comment: You'll have to wait. Once uploaded to YT, the lower res variants are generated first. Eventually, the 720p/1080p will show up.